# LoadRunner Parameterization: Question about "Unique"

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a script. In that script, I have a login value that I have parameterized. The script will be run back in Controller as a performance test, with 15 VUsers. The test will be executed for a period of 2 hours. Each VUser will run the script multiple times (multiple iterations). I want to ensure that the 15 logins I have are only used ONCE for each iteration by each of the 15 VUsers, and that none of the VUsers select the same parameterized login value.

What is the best Parameter setting for this purpose? Is it Select Next Row: Unique and Update Value on: Each Iteration?

Comment: What does your training manual and the software manual/help suggest?   Have you simulated the parameter option and found it to be correct for your need?

Comment: @JamesPulley not sure how I reply to you, but upon finding a manual, it looks like Unique / Once will pull a unique login ID and use it for the duration of the performance test.

Comment: Try other options for unique and simulate the parameter.  Be Curious.  This precise question is covered as part of standard product training, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Go for Unique Once setting.
For example if you have 5 Vusers (u1, u2, u3, u4, u5) and 5 logins parameterised(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5)
Unique once will assign one login to each user. like u1:l1, u2:l2, U3:l3, u4:l4, u5:l5.
Unique each iteration might fail your script if you do not have sufficient login variables but if you have then the vuser will use unique value from the parameter file on every iteration. Also every vuser will use unique value.